# Recursive regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, recursion

I've got strings like these:

```
| Released    = {{start-date|June 14, 1972}}
| Released    = {{Start date|1973|03|01|df=y}}
```

I'd like to replace all | within {{ }} with ^

```
| Released    = {{start-date^June 14, 1972}}
| Released    = {{Start date^1973^03^01^df=y}}
```

I can't use substring replacement because there are | symbols outside {{ }}, which must be left intact. And because I don't know exactly how many parts does the string in {{ }} have, I can't use something like `s/{{(.+?)\|(.+?)}}/{{$1^$2}}/`.

I suppose I need to use some kind of recursion here?

Comment: I'll work on an answer momentarily, but I just couldn't resist the comment "you are scraping something from Wikipedia, right?"

Comment: And if that's the case, it will probably behoove you to know that the only 100%-working parser for wikitext is MediaWiki itself (and even that can be buggy sometimes).

Comment: Yes. I know about dbpedia.org and some other similar resources but can't use them because data is too outdated for my task.

Comment: I don't need to parse all wikitext features and definitely don't need to render it to HTML…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
s/\|(?=[^{}\n]*}})/^/g
```

Even simpler solution, but probably broken in many cases:

```
s/(?!^)\|/^/gm
```

Here is a bit more robust regex:

```
s/(?:\G(?!^)(?:(?>[^|]*?}})(?>.*?{{))*|^(?>.*?{{))(?>[^|]*?(?=}}|\|))\K\|(?=.*?}})/^/gs;
```

Commented:

```
s/
(?:
  \G(?!^)                       # inside of a {{}} tag
  (?: (?>[^|]*?}}) (?>.*?{{) )* # read till we find a | in another tag if none in current
  |
  ^(?>.*?{{)                    # outside of tag, parse till in
)
(?> [^|]*? (?=}}|\|) )          # eat till a | or end of tag
\K                              # don't include stuff to the left of \K in the match
\|                              # the |
(?=.*?}})                       # just to make sure the tag is closed
/^/gsx;
```

Input:

```
|}}
| Re|eased    = {{start-date|June 14^, {|1972}|x}}
| Released    = {{Start date}|1973|03|01}|df=y|}}
| || {{|}} {{ |
```

Output:

```
|}}
| Re|eased    = {{start-date^June 14^, {^1972}^x}}
| Released    = {{Start date}^1973^03^01}^df=y^}}
| || {{^}} {{ |
```

Example: http://ideone.com/fbY2W

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know about lookaheads :(  Slightly modified to my needs — works fine!

Comment: +1 for a nice obfuscated code exammple, 12 lines of comments and I still cannot understand it. I think one line per character would do it :D

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the most concise way to do it, but it's the first working method I came up with.

```
my $new;
for ( split /({{.*?}})/ ) {
    s/\|/^/g if /^{{/;
    $new .= $_;
}
$_ = $new;
```

Comment: This does not work because you have a greedy `.*` in your split regex.  When I apply it to `"A {{b|c}} c|d {{e|f|}} g h"` I get `"A {{b^c}} c^d {{e^f^}} g h"` which incorrectly turns the pipe between `c` and `d` into a caret.

Comment: Replace the `split` with `split /({{.*?}})/`, that should do it.

Comment: @Ray Toal: Good catch. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Flimzy I knew you would. +1 now. Nice answer. I was sort of surprised it works without escaping the left brace; technically that is a metacharacter.

Answer (score 2):

```
s{({{.*?}})}
 {my $x = $1;
  $x =~ tr/|/^/;
  $x
 }ge;
```